# GROOVY: Distinguish between generics asType casting method

Tags: java, groovy

Is there a way to distinguish b vs c via asType method in class A?

```
class A<T>{
    T asType(Class<?> c){
        //how do I distinguish between generic types?
    }
}

def a = new A()

def b = a as List<String>
def c = a as List<Integer>
```

Comment: Can anyone help with this question?

Comment: Because of type erasure, I don't think what you want is possible. You need create an object to retain the generic information like TypeReference object

Comment: @aristotll I see. Can you provide an example showing what you mean?